# Get data from a text file using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a text file that on one of the lines contains 
"#define VERSION_NUMBER 0011"
I need to find that line and assign the 4 digit value "0011" to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

`VAR=$(cat file | grep "#define VERSION_NUMBER" | awk '{print $3}')`

This does seem kind of backwards though. Is it possible to change your build scripts to pass `-DVERSION_NUMBER=0011` and define the version number that way? Then it can be stored in a simple language independent text file containing nothing else.

Comment: or `... | awk -F= '{print $NF}'`, Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use grep and regex, once grep returns a value, you can assign that value to a bash variable fairly easily. Following is working test code:

`` $ echo "#define VERSION_NUMBER 0011" > test.c
$ c=`cat test.c | sed -n -e 's/^#define VERSION_NUMBER \([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\1/p'`
$ echo $c
0011 ``

### Broken Down

This is the important line:

`` c=`cat test.c | sed -n -e 's/^#define VERSION_NUMBER \([0-9]\{4\}\)$/\1/p'` ``

Broken down it is composed of `c`, the variable name is assigned to the evaluation (`` `...` ``) of the `sed` command. The sed command is where the regex is. What I came up with is:

- `^`: the line starts with
- `#define VERSION_NUMBER`: a text literal, this will be character-for-character in the string.
- `\(...\)`: an escaped set of parens that make up a match portion.
- `[0-9]`: in the match, a number exists (0 to 9).
- `\{4\}`: the preceding number repeats 4 times exactly.

  - you could use `*` here for any number of matches, `\{4,\}` for 4 or more, or `\{4,6\}` for 4-6 matches.
- `$`: end of the line

When this is run, sed emits the number, and since we assigned sed's evaluation to `c`, `c` now contains that number.

### Issues

Possible issues are that this does not take whitespace into account, if there is a tab or space at the beginning or end of this line, it will fail.

**Confession**: I had to learn a little unix regex to answer this, reference: [smugbook](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html).